# Deploy solution only at root sites in site collections

Tags: sharepoint-server, solution-deployment

There are more than 100 site collections and I need to deploy a solution which should only be available to all site collections but not to sub-sites.
Please suggest a way forward.

Comment: To better understand what you want, you need to have your features available on root web of each site collection but not for sub-sites ?

Comment: Yes, this is what exactly I want.

Comment: Like @Nadeem said, solutions are deployed to either all web applications or single web application. You can control (in some cases) the scope of your feature depending on the elements contained. If a feature is scoped to site collection, it will appear only for site collection administrator. You could also use Sandboxed solution with web scoped feature and upload them to the webs you need automatically. This can ensure that feature is only available in the web where you uploaded your solution, this can be a valid workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is deployed either globally (all web applications) or a single application. What you are looking for is perhaps a feature. A feature can be Scoped to site collection, apart from Farm, Web application and Web.